# How to exempt specific cells from rules in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, formulas

I am trying to use conditional formatting in Excel to alert users to duplicate S/N's entered in a column but have the rule ignore "N/A" or anything that has spaces (i.e., a note or message)... so ignore anything that isn't a duplicate S/N.

Is this possible using conditional formatting or will I have to delve into writing some custom formula?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should provide some sample data, expected result / behavior and the actual result you are getting with your approach... that way you help others to help you...

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to use a custom formula, here is one:

```
=AND(IFERROR(ERROR.TYPE(A1),0)<>7,1<COUNTIF(A:A,A1))
```

This will exclude cells with #N/A. If  you want to also exclude other errors, you can apply the ISERROR function.

Comment: Good answer, but please use the {} icon to format your code.